# Overridden dunder methods reset by PySpark on collection

Tags: python, pyspark

I trying to use PySpark to do a small number of transformations to data in a JSON Lines text file. The data is a number of dicts that I need transformed into a namedTuple with an overridden `__eq__` method. Here's what it looks like

```
class TaggedAndLabeled(namedtuple("Foo", "tags labels")):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.labels
```

I could do what I need (namely, returning the position of a `TaggedAndLabeled` object if a label is in it's labels) with a list comp but I thought it'd be cleaner or more clever with an overridden `__eq__`. The problem is that this part of the object (I think) doesn't survive deserialization once it goes through PySpark.

Lets say the data looks like this

```
{"id": [0], "labels": ["foo", "bar"]}
{"id": [1], "labels": ["biz", "baz"]}
{"id": [2], "labels": ["spam", "ham"]}
```

Then this is the result of using PySpark to read in and transform the data.

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple
from pyspark import SparkContext

class TaggedAndLabeled(namedtuple("Foo", "tags labels")):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.labels


def main(data, neg_size_multiplier=10):

    sc = SparkContext()

    raw_data = sc.textFile(data)
    tagged_data = raw_data.map(json.loads)
                          .map(lambda data: TaggedAndLabeled(tuple(data['id']), tuple(data['labels'])))

    a = TaggedAndLabeled(tuple([0]), tuple(['foo', 'bar']))
    b = tagged_data.collect()
    print(a == 'foo')
    print(b[0] == 'foo')
```

Prints

```
True
False
```

I wanted to point out this happens with all dunder methods. If I override `__str__` it's replaced with the default one from Object on collection which makes me thing this is a deserialization issue.